# Modeling considerations when data spans different events (time) and exhibit a (relatively) low mean and high variance

Tags: predictive-models, modeling, model-evaluation, predictor, lags

I have weekday data ($n = 1551$) from the past 5 years (2019-2023) with attendance at a large restaurant. I am just getting started, and for each weekday I calculated the mean and the variance as per (rounded to 0 decimals):

| Weekday | Mean | Variance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mon | 48 | 1320 |
| Tue | 51 | 1505 |
| Wed | 49 | 1490 |
| Thu | 47 | 1531 |
| Fri | 44 | 1326 |

In other words, the variance is rather large in comparison to the mean for each day. I want to build a model that predicts the number of visitors. For this I have considered investigating a Time-series model (such as AR($p$) with a Kahlman filter and also a regression-based model (I am open to suggestions to research :) ).

My questions / considerations;

- What type of evaluation metric/combination of metrics could be suitable to use given the (relative) low mean and high variance?
- As my data spans over several years, there are bound to be some differences during covid / after covid. They also moved the restaurant to a new location during summer 2023. I was thinking to deal with this by incorporating a lagged variable. Are there other ways I could do it?